# How do give a random string in StringBody() in gatling?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I am newbie to the Gatling tool.

I want to give a random string in the `StringBody()` method. 
For example, for 100 requests there are 100 different strings that will be passed.

Here is my sample code:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
class LoadTest extends Simulation {

  private val csvFeeder = csv("data.csv").random
  val httpConf = http
    .baseURL("http://localhost:5000/sample")   
    .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/json,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")

  val scn = scenario("load test")
    .feed(csvFeeder)
    .exec(http("request")
    .post("http://localhost:5000/sample")
    .body(StringBody(s"""{"inputData": ${csvFeeder} }""")).asJSON
  setUp(
    scn.inject(
      constantUsersPerSec(50)
      during (10 seconds) randomized).protocols(httpConf))
}
```

But all the strings in the CSV file are passed.

What is the problem in my code?
How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this :

```
import scala.util.Random

    var randomString = Iterator.continually(Map("randstring" -> ( Random.alphanumeric.take(35).mkString )))// length of the random string is 35 chars here

    val scn = scenario("load test")
        .feed(randomString)
        .exec(http("request")
        .post("http://localhost:5000/sample")
        .body(StringBody("""{"inputData": ${randstring} }""")).asJSON
      setUp(
        scn.inject(
          constantUsersPerSec(50)
          during (10 seconds) randomized).protocols(httpConf))
    }
```

Also in your code change:  `.body(StringBody(s"""{"inputData": ${csvFeeder} }""")).asJSON` to `.body(StringBody("""{"inputData": ${csv_header_coloumn_name} }""")).asJSON`
//csv_header_coloumn_name > is the field from the csv file you want to replace.